# How to use redux hooks in getInitialProps

Tags: redux, react-redux, next.js

I have been trying to persist my redux store through a reload. I was using useEffect to dispatch my actions at first but then when I tried to reload the page router became undefined and I got a 500 error. After that I tried using getInitialProps and use the ctx.query.id but I ran into another error saying that hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

How do I make it so hooks work inside of getInitialProps and what is the best way of persisting my store data through a reload?

```
export default function CarPage() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const router = useRouter()
  const car = useSelector((state) => state.cars.car)

  /*
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!car && router) {
      dispatch(getCar(router.query.id))
    }
  }, [])
  */

  return (
      <Container>
        <h2>{car.model}</h2>
      </Container>
  )
}

CarPage.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  dispatch(getCar(ctx.query.id))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To persist redux store through a page reload, we definitely need to use browser storage.
I suggest using https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist.

To use `dispatch` inside `getInitialProps`, please try with this code snippet instead of using `useDispatch()` hook.

```
CarPage.getInitialProps = async ({ store, query }) => {
   store.dispatch(getCar(query.id));
   return { initialState: store.getState() };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Richard. My ctx doesn't contain store for some reason. Does that mean that I am initializing my store the wrong way?

 I will check out this lib as well, thanks.